# Create a Linked Server for a MySQL Database in SQL Server 2005

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, odbc, linked-server

I'm currently trying something I've never done before - I'm trying to access MySQL data in an SQL Server environment. Where I am, we have two servers (the MySQL and MSSQL servers), and each stores different types of data. Recently I've found a need to write queries that include data for both servers. One of the ways I read to do this is adding a "Linked Server" in SQL Server. But try as I might I cannot seem to get a Linked Server added.

I am working on a Windows 7 system, our SQL Server instance is 2005, and the MySQL version is 5.5.31.

What I've done so far is this:

- Downloaded and installed the [MySQL ODBC drivers](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html)
- Created a System DSN using that driver for the MySQL database, called "Production". (I also tested the connection from the Data Sources application and it connects just fine).
- Checked for the Provider in SQL Server (MSDASQL) to configure options such as "allow nested queries" and "allow 'LIKE' operator"
- right click on Linked Servers in Server Objects in SQL Server > "New Linked Server"

From here, I fill out the linked server info like this:

---

```
 Checked "Other data source" (not SQL Server)

 Chose Provider "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers"

 Product Name: "Production"

 Data Source: (the name of the System DSN) Production
```

---

Then in the security tab, I chose the "Connections will be made using this security context" and provided my username and login for the MySQL server.

Then this is where I run into an error every time. I always get the following error message:

> The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "FLUX".
>   OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "FLUX" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.5000&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=7303&LinkId=20476

If you click that link for help, by the way, nothing shows up.
I saw other people suggested trying an older MySQL ODBC driver, adding a System Data Source for the 32bit driver as well as the 64bit driver, and restarting my machine (not the DB server) -- none of these fixed my error.

What I do not understand is why my System DSN seems to work and connect fine, but SQL Server cannot see the Data Source. Does anyone see what I'm missing, or what I might be configuring incorrectly?

**EDIT**
Clarified that I restarted my local machine, but not the DB server since trying to add the Linked Server.

Answer (score 0):

From everything you've said, you *probably* have a mismatch between bitnesses of SQL Server 2005 components and the installed ODBC Driver for MySQL.

[System DSNs](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin) are definitely the way to go.

You probably will need to [install both the 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC driver](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/dataspace/owiki/wiki/UdaWikiWeb/MsSqlOn64bitWin), and configure an identical (same name and everything!) System DSN with each.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you may also want/need to install this patch it was useful for getting XP and 2003 to work properly for ODBC type connections for me.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=000364db-5e8b-44a8-b9be-ca44d18b059b&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Is your Database server on the same machine on which you have Sql Server Management Studio Installed? If the SQL Server is on a remote machine then you need to install the ODBC driver on remote Machine and create the DSN there as per [link](http://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb01039.html)

I was having the same issue but the above link solved my problem.